# logging.handler.TimedRotatingFileHandler does not work correctly on the server

Tags: python, logging, logrotate

I am implementing `logging` for some `streaming` functions in a `faust` app, which has been implemented by python.

I wanted to save all the logs of each specific streaming file in a separate folder, and also separate my logs based on the day on which they have been created.

Here is the structure of my faust app:
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk7cx.png)

And this is the structure of my logs folder:[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6gsj.png)

I have included a different `logger` object for every file(I know that it's not clean code).
for example for **rule_checking.py**, I have the below code:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

if not os.path.exists(BASE_DIR + "/streaming/logs/rule_checking_logs"):
    os.makedirs(BASE_DIR+"/streaming/logs/rule_checking_logs")

rule_checking_logger = logging.getLogger('rule_checking_logging')
rule_checking_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
rule_checking_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler("logs/rule_checking_logs/rule_checking.log",
                                                            when="D",
                                                            backupCount=30)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(filename)s - %(funcName)s - %(lineno)d - %(message)s')
rule_checking_handler.setFormatter(formatter)                                                                   
rule_checking_logger.addHandler(rule_checking_handler)
```

And for **tracking_checking.py**:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

if not os.path.exists(BASE_DIR + "/streaming/logs/tracking_checking_logs"):
    os.makedirs(BASE_DIR+"/streaming/logs/tracking_checking_logs")

tracking_checking_logger = logging.getLogger('tracking_checking_logging')
tracking_checking_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
tracking_checking_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler("logs/tracking_checking_logs/tracking_checking.log",
                                                            when="D",
                                                            backupCount=30)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(filename)s - %(funcName)s - %(lineno)d - %(message)s')
tracking_checking_handler.setFormatter(formatter)                                                                
tracking_checking_logger.addHandler(tracking_checking_handler)
```

Today when I was working with the server(`Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)`), I noticed that only two files have been created:

```
rule_checking.log  rule_checking.log.2022-10-20
```

The contents of the above files are really weird to me.
In the **rule_checking.log** file, there are some logs that have been created in 10-24:

```
2022-10-24 07:30:28,935 - INFO - rule_checking_logging - rule_checking.py - check_rules - 158 - The condition fires is: [False, False, False]
2022-10-24 07:30:28,935 - INFO - rule_checking_logging - rule_checking.py - check_rules - 196 - The event is ended
```

And in the **rule_checking.log.2022-10-20**, there are some logs for 10-21:

```
2022-10-21 09:45:20,738 - INFO - rule_checking_logging - rule_checking.py - check_rules - 113 - The feature is: location
2022-10-21 09:45:20,738 - INFO - rule_checking_logging - rule_checking.py - check_rules - 131 - The feature 247 value is 247
2022-10-21 09:45:20,738 - INFO - rule_checking_logging - rule_checking.py - check_rules - 134 -  The operation: in
```

I can not figure out the reason for this inconsistency, but I will be grateful for any help and guide.